# Why is the server sending an H264 NAL unit in 5 udp packets?

Tags: udp, wifi, h.264, packet

I'm pulling H264 packets from a Tello drone to send to a codec and I've run into something odd. The drone will often send 5 packets, but only one will have the H264 header (00, 00, 00, 01). Is it splitting the NAL unit into 5 packets? Why? Isn't the max UDP packet much larger than 1460 bytes? I've attached a picture of a group of packets I received where I've marked the packets that have a header.

[image]

EDIT: As requested [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YEJnZvJZG83iiJ67q2zLb50veK2pchlJ?usp=sharing)'s a collection of H264 packets that I pulled. If you have Wireshark, the .pcapng file will show them graphically. Otherwise the raw text file will show them as text

Comment: Minaro - this could be an interesting question if you could share the data that is in the actual UDP packets.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I've gone ahead and put some of the packets into a shareable google drive folder

Comment: While UDP packet can be as large 64KiB underling protocol (ethernet) limits MTU to 1500 bytes or smaller (in your case the limit look like to be 1460 bytes without headers overhead).